# Pentaho JNDI ssh tunneling Data Integration MySQL

Tags: mysql, jndi, pentaho, ssh-tunnel, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to access a database server using **SSH tunneling**, credentials are fine, as i have tested this on **MYSQL GUI Client using SSH Tunneling option**, i have also just tested this using command line and command line connection to server is also working perfectly using below commands on two command line terminals:

1. ssh root@192.168.1.1 -L 3307:localhost:3306
2. mysql -h localhost -P 3307 -u qstats -pPassw0rd stats

But when i try to connect to the database server using pentaho it gives error as

**Access denied for user 'stats'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

I then used **JNDI** and gave the credentials there, but still it does not work, my JNDI settings are as follow:

Asterisk/type=javax.sql.DataSource

Asterisk/driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Asterisk/user=qstats

Asterisk/password=Passw0rd

Asterisk/url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/stats

Please if someone can help?

Comment: I Had tried in the past and Tunneling is not working in pentaho.

Comment: It worked for me. once i had initiated the ssh connection in parallel using CMD :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initiate the SSH connection separately using CMD to the database server and then try to connect using PDI, and connection will be successful. BUT JNDI still don't work, only direct connection works.

Comment: it is 2022 and you still cannot. do ssh connection from ETL packages

Comment: Good old days, i still remember this fatigue :D